Azure DevOps release of ADF from Dev to Prod. How to make that the release do not affects the Linked Services
I have 2 main subscriptions, Develop and Production, with its specific ADF project.
Both Data Factories have exactly the same version, but the only main differences are the Linked Services: Dev LS are pointing to Dev ddbb meanwhile Prod LS are pointing to Prod ddbb.
When making a Release in Azure DevOps, from Dev to Prod, I want to be sure that these LinkedServices are changed and Prod LS do not end pointing to Dev ddbb.
For being able to do it so, what are the 'Override template parameters' that I should input?
Thanks!
Searched for some variable names to override, but found no help for this main problem.


what are the 'Override template parameters' that I should input?

For the task AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3, you can refer to the ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json which can be found in the pipeline artifact or source repo to know which ADF parameters are available and can be replaced.

To replace with new Linked service, i defined AzureStorageLinkedService_connectionString above and overrride it in the task.

I have applied this and have not been able to deploy the project correctly.
Specifically, I changed the Catalog option in the _connectionString (from pointing to ddbb_prod to pointing to ddbb_dev) and made the -factoryName "adf-project-02".
After a successful release, no changes were noticed in adf-project-02, not only did the linked services remain the same, but new pipelines I created for testing purposes also appeared.

It works on my side, the linked service name didn't change as it's not overridden. Check the code on linked service from ADF, it points to the new one.

The way for pointing out the deployment destination project is just by overriding the "-factoryName" in the template parameters, rigth?
So if I want to make a release from adf-project-1 to adf-project-2, I would just have to overriede the table parameter such as -factoryName "adf-project-2"

yes, if you only override the -factoryName, it will deploy same linked service to new ADF,  also make sure the service connection used has permission on the new ADF for deployment.
